# Regex to detect hyphen character

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, email

Live demo: http://regex101.com/r/wW6wC4

---

I'm trying to add a regex expression that allows email addresses like:

```
asdf.asdf@test-dom-a.com

([\w+\.]+@[\w]{1,})(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]{1,})
                                     ^---- Thought this would allow hyphens...
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: It does allow hyphens, but you've positioned it so it only allows hyphens after the first `.` after the `@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern requires that the hyphen appears after a period. Try this instead:

```
([\w+.]+@[\w-]{1,})(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regex101.com/r/gI2gP1)

Or more simply:

```
([\w+.]+@[\w.-]+)
```

Although the second pattern doesn't *require* that the second part of the address contains a period.

[**Demonstration**](http://regex101.com/r/fK1iH7)

Comment: This regex only matches the very first email address in the list, nothing else.

Comment: @Serg I've tested it in the exact same tool from your question. It matches all the input patterns.

Comment: @Serg It's possible you didn't have the `g` (global) flag on when you tested it the first time. That would explain why it only matched the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex:

```
([\w+\.]+@[\w]{1,})(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]{1,})
```

This will allow hyphen as last character only.

To allow it anywhere use:

```
^([\w+.-]+@[\w-])(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z.-])$
```

OR to allow it only **in between** use (except first and last position):

```
^[\w+.-]*@\w[\w-]*\.[\w-]*[0-9a-zA-Z.]+$
```

**Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lQ1nV7**

Comment: Wouldn't this only allow one character to appear at the end?

Comment: This doesn't work on his example case. You've added the `-` in the wrong character class, I think.

Comment: you need a `+` before the `$`

Comment: `This will only allow hyphen as last character.` not really.

Comment: @Rawling: What I meant was that it will allow hyphen as last character only. (only was misplaced I think)

Comment: @anubhava No, it'll allow hyphen as any character after the first `.` after the `@`. If there is a hyphen, it doesn't have to be the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Your hyphen code appears in the segment that checks characters *after* the first period in the domain name.  You need to add it to the match block *before* the domain name:

```
([\w+\.]+@[\w\-]{1,})(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]{1,})
             ^^----  check here as well.
```

In reality, I would search for a more comprehensive email regex - the one you have doesn't seem robust enough IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You're not matching strings of the form "asd@fge.hj-kl", which as you can see not what you want.

```
([\w+\.]+)@([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]{1,})\.com
([\w+\.]+)@([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]{1,})\.([\w]{1,})
```